# grep for specific process in ps but not the grep command itself

Tags: grep, process, ps

If I want to check if something is running, I do `ps aux | grep flamethrower`, expecting just to show the processes containing `flamethrower` in the name. This will always find at least one process, as `grep flamethrower` matches this criteria.

Is there some way to check for a specific process, in a *cleaner* way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way would be to use [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep):

```
$ pgrep init
1
2215
6300
$ ps ax | grep init
    1 ?        Ss     6:41 /sbin/init
 2215 ?        Ss     1:54 init --user --restart --state-fd 26
 6300 ?        S      0:00 init --user --startup-event indicator-services-start
17522 pts/10   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto init
```

Note that you might need to use other tricks with `pgrep` as well, if you use it with `watch` and `-f`:

```
$ watch pgrep init -fa
Every 2.0s: pgrep init -fa                                                                                                                                                                                               
Wed Dec  3 19:19:47 2014

1 /sbin/init
2215 init --user --restart --state-fd 26
6300 init --user --startup-event indicator-services-start
18233 watch pgrep init -fa
18234 watch pgrep init -fa
18235 sh -c pgrep init -fa
$ watch pgrep [i]nit -fa
Every 2.0s: pgrep [i]nit -fa                                                                                                                                                                                           Wed Dec  3 19:20:42 2014

1 /sbin/init
2215 init --user --restart --state-fd 26
6300 init --user --startup-event indicator-services-start
```

Comment: BTW, congrats on getting to 2k!

Comment: I would use `ps ax | grep [i]nit` (this work for a fixed string of course)

Comment: @Archemar I need to do that with `pgrep` too, if use it with `watch`.

Comment: @slm thanks. Looking forward to more involvement here.

Comment: But: from [`pgrep` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep): «The process name used for matching is limited to the 15 characters present in the output of _/proc/pid/stat_.  Use the -f option to match against the complete command line, _/proc/pid/cmdline_.», So, what if I wan't to search on process complete (not-truncated) names (without full path or arguments)?

Comment: @PabloBianchi what's the name here? Name of the executable, or argv[0]?

Comment: @muru [Name of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176059/4970442) but not `/proc/PID/comm` (truncated as _Name_ on `status`), the last part of cmdline. A guy called [Luben Tuikov](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0606.2/3139.html) also thing would be nice more bytes.

Comment: @PabloBianchi you'd have to script that, since `comm`, `stat` have truncated names, `cmdline` would have argv[0] (so may not be the executable name). In bash, for example: `for proc in $(ps -eo pid=); do f=$(readlink /proc/$proc/exe); [[ ${f##*/} =~ pattern ]] && echo $proc; done`